# How programmatically get the path of a file in the project folder in Xcode(Swift)?

Tags: swift, xcode

Anybody could tell me how I can find the path of the Result.txt programmatically?Thanks. [Project Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt8Fp.png)

Edit: The "Result.txt" is not visible form the Xcode, And I do not want to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Result", withExtension: "txt"){
     print("File path : \(file)")
 }
```

Comment: Thank for quick answer, but using Bundle is not just for the folders, which are visible from Xcode?The "Result.txt" is not visible form Xcode, and I do not want to be visible from Xcode. @Sh_Khan

Comment: anyway file must be dragged to the project , you can't reference a file out of project